# Float navigation elements on the left and right sides of content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float two 'navigation' elements on either side of some content. These elements should stay in place (and visible) as a user scrolls down a page.

Example: (see less than and greater than signs):  http://jsfiddle.net/dbough/tASs2/

I've tried to 'fix' both elements in place with position:fixed, but it causes the elements to collapse together

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbough/tASs2/1/

Looking for direction on how to make this work.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
        <span id="nav_left">&nbsp;&lt;</span> 
        <span id="nav_right">&nbsp;&gt;</span>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        SOME CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (without fixed positioning)

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    padding:auto;
    max-width: 400px;
}
#content{
    margin:auto;
    padding:auto;
}
#nav_left, #nav_right{
    max-width: 10px;
    font-size: 200%;
}
#nav_left {
        margin-left:-10%;
}
#nav_right {
    float:right;
    margin-right:-10%;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tASs2/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `position:absolute` to arrow classes and `relative` to the parent div `#container`

```
#nav_left {
        left:0; position:absolute
}
#nav_right {
    right:0; position:absolute
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tASs2/2/)**

---

**For Fixed Arrows**

Use a `relative` div inside the `fixed` div and align the child div by `position:absolute`

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
           <div id="wrap"> 
               <div id="nav_left">&lt;&nbsp;</div> <div id="nav_right">&nbsp;&gt;</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav{position:fixed;  
    width:100%; 
    height:40px;
}
#wrap{
    position:relative; 
    width:100%; 
    height:40px;
}
#nav_left {
        left:15%;
    position:absolute
}
#nav_right {
    right:15%;
    position:absolute
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/tASs2/6/)**

**Or** in simple method give direct `position:fixed` to the child divs and remove the outer divs

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav_left">&lt;&nbsp;</div> <div id="nav_right">&nbsp;&gt;</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav_left {
        left:15%;
    position:fixed
}
#nav_right {
    right:15%;
    position:fixed
}
```

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/tASs2/7/)**

Comment: ALmost there.  I forgot to add these elements should stay in place (and visible) as a user scrolls down a page.  I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

When using `position: fixed` you should be using the `top`/`bottom`/`right`/`left` attributes too and not use `float` or margins. See the W3C CSS spec about [position](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#positioning-scheme).

See http://jsfiddle.net/pqbkN/

I this case you should change your arrow `span`s to:

```
#nav_left {
    /*margin-left:-10%;*/
    left: 2em;
    top: 1em;
}
#nav_right {
    /*float:right;*/
    right: 4em;
    top: 1em;
    /*margin-right:-10%;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for fixed version at #nav-right not margin-right:10% but right:10%.